# How to parse '<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "red" : "blue"} />'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I think I understand why the first instance of **isActive** that's passed as an argument to the arrow function is encapsulated in curly brackets, i.e. *{ isActive }*, while the second *isActive* is not encapsulated in curly brackets, but would like to be sure I understand correctly.

Is the first "isActive" that's encapsulated in curly brackets i.e., *({ isActive })* an example of Object Destructuring ? (If not, doesn't an arrow function in JS expect to receive the name of a variable, but doesn't *{ isActive }* evaluate to *true* or *false*?)

Am I right that this is an example of Object Destructuring?

Comment: I think that line should be `<NavLink className={isActive ? "red" : "blue"} />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is right. `react-router` **v6** has changed the [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink) API a bit. You need to provide the `isActive` wrapped in an object as opposed to in [NavLink v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).

```
export interface NavLinkProps
  extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style" | "children"> {
  children:
    | React.ReactNode
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  className?: string | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string | undefined);
  end?: boolean;
  style?:
    | React.CSSProperties
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.CSSProperties);
}
```